# Susbtitute behaviour of a method call in constructor with typemock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor, typemock

So I am asked to test this constructor call.

```
public class testClass
{
  private bool keyValue = 45;
  public testClass()
  {
    MethodOne();

    keyValue = 900;
    MethodTwo();
    MethodThree();
    keyValue = 221;
  }
}
```

In the code above, keyValue(global field) is constantly being set.
The methods use keyValue in each decision making algorithm.
I want to assert that keyValue is set to this value.

Getting the current values of fields is possible by using

```
Isolate.whenCalled(() => obj.MethodOne())
.DoInstead(context => 
{
   testClass object = (testClass)context.Instance;
   // from here on, get any fields
});
```

I find that the code above could only be done anywhere except for the constructor.(correct me if I am wrong)

Another point is that I could only mock methods before the constructor is ran only by using the MockManager API.

```
[Test]
public void testMethod()
{
    Mock mockObj = MockManager.Mock(typeof(testClass));
    mockObj.ExpectCall("MethodOne");

    //instantiate tested object 
    testClass testedObj = new testClass();
}
```

Although the code above asserts that MethodOne() is called in the constructor,
I could not alter its behaviour to check the fields.

Any enlightment/ help would really help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just be clear, are you saying that in your mocked `MethodOne()` you need check the value of `keyValue` but can't because it is private?

Comment: being private is not a problem. my main concern is how to get the current state of the object(and current field values). THis is possible with Isolate api but I do not know how to mock methods with this api before an instance is created.

Comment: Ah ok I get it. I'm not familiar with Typemock (I use Moq) but I'm going to suggest that putting that functionality in the constructor may not be a good idea for the purposes of testing. Constructors generally just set initial state rather than instigate functionality, and you can't define constructors in interfaces either. Is it possible for you to move the constructor code into a `Process()` method for instance?

Comment: Yeah I am well aware of that It is a really bad design decission. Unfortunately, I could not refactor any of the tested code.  It is a wierd situation the project is in actually. But that is why we are using typemock Isolator, to test the normally untestable bits of code.

Comment: as is often the case ;) I may got shot for suggesting this but how about create a wrapper class with a `Process()` method that creates the instance you want to test and then mock the wrapper class? A bit shady I know.

Comment: It is still the same thing.I am after setting up a mock for a future instance. putting the instantiation code anywhere will still be the same. I will extend my mockmanager api example to be clear.

Comment: @AngeloCharl i don't quite understand what is your goal in this test, can you explain what exactly you are trying to test that i could try and help...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

> I want to assert that keyValue is set to this value

a relevant test would be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Fake the object, Ignore calls, Invoke original ctor
    testClass tc = Isolate.Fake.Instance<testClass>(Members.ReturnNulls, ConstructorWillBe.Called);

    // Create a getter for keyValue and call it's original implementation
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => tc.KeyVal).CallOriginal();

    // Assert that by the end of the ctor keyValue is equal to 221
    Assert.AreEqual(221, tc.KeyVal); 
}
```

Is this what you had in mind?